# Computing an HMAC-SHA signature

Tags: amazon-simpledb, krl, hmac

I'm writing a module for Amazon's SimpleDB. They require REST requests to be signed using HMAC-SHA algorithm. ([Details here.](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonSimpleDB/latest/DeveloperGuide/index.html?HMACAuth.html))

I'm told that there is a function to computer this signature, but I can't find it in the [documentation](http://docs.kynetx.com/docs/Math#Digest_functions). What is the function called, and what do its arguments look like?

Comment: See http://ktest.heroku.com/a421x67 https://gist.github.com/980000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDITED: The following should work:

```
pre {
  message = "Four score and seven years ago";
  key = "Abe Lincoln";
  signature = math:hmac_sha256_base64(message, key);
}
notify("Signature is", signature);
```

The function is `math:hmac_sha256_base64(<datastring>,<keystring>)`

Comment: Thanks, Randall. I'm still having trouble getting it to actually work with AWS, but that is the right syntax.

Answer (score 1):

The HMAC is a standard function that can be found in crypto libraries for most platforms. Amazon shows several examples on the documentaion page you link to.

For Java, you can find it in [javax.crypto.Mac](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/crypto/Mac.html)

For .Net, look in [System.Security.Cryptography](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hmacsha1.aspx)

For [KRL](http://apps.kynetx.com/), I haven't found any built-in stock solution. Since it seems possible to embed javascript, the [jsSHA](http://jssha.sourceforge.net/) implemenation could be useful. There is a [sha1](http://docs.kynetx.com/docs/Math#sha1) function in the math library, and implementing HMAC according to [RFC2104](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2104.html) doesn't seem that difficult.

Comment: Thanks. I'm looking for information on the function in KRL (hence the KRL tag).

Comment: Oh, never heard of it. Looks interesting, I'll look around and update my answer if I find anything.

Answer (score 1):

To sign strings with embedded newlines (AWS I'm talking to you!) you have to do the following (based on the AWS S3 example)

```
pre {
  raw_string = uri:unescape("GET%0A%0A%0AWed, 28 Mar 2007 01:29:59 +0000%0A/");
  sample_key = "uV3F3YluFJax1cknvbcGwgjvx4QpvB+leU8dUj2o";
  signature = math:hmac_sha1_base64(raw_string, sample_key);
  expected = "Db+gepJSUbZKwpx1FR0DLtEYoZA=";
  passfail = (signature eq expected) => "pass" | "fail";
}
```

The `uri:decode()` function returns a string with proper newlines, where `\n\n\n` does not. You might have to add trailing '=' to the signature.